# Are there any practical drop-in replacements for BSTs in the case where data are integers?

Tags: data-structures, integers

There are a number of specialized data structures that implement ordered dictionaries for integer keys: [van Emde Boas trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree), [y-Fast tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie), [fusion trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_tree), etc. Each of these data structures implement the key ordered dictionary primitives in sublogarithmic time.

However, to the best of my knowledge, all three of the above data structures are interesting only in a theoretical context, since their hidden constant factors are so large that they're effectively impractical. (I may be wrong about that, though!)

Are there any integer data structures that support sublogarithmic query times in theory which are also efficient in practice?

Comment: vEB trees have very low constant factors.

Comment: @jbapple Do you have a source on that? The last time I read up on this they weren't practical, in part due to poor cache locality from their high memory usage.

Comment: No, I simply counted it up. As for cache locality, a binary search tree has at least $log_2 n + \Omega(1)$ cache misses, on average, per search, ans uses at least $2n$ words of space. vEB trees can use arrays (if the keys are dense in the universe) or hash tables and use no more than $O(n)$ words of space, with a small constant. In fact, when using arrays, the space usage can be brought down to $O(n)$ *bits* of space!

Comment: @jbapple I'm not sure that constant factors are things you can "count up." They often have to be determined empirically. As for locality - there are fewer nodes visited in a vEB tree, as you noted, but those nodes are so huge that they're likely to cache poorly, while a BST often will keep its nodes in cache because they take up such little space, particularly if you have a few nodes you access a lot. As for space usage - are you sure about that? vEB trees use space proportional to the universe size, not the number of elements stored (unless I'm mistaken?)

Comment: OK, in order: 1. You can "count up" constant factors by counting operations. That is what "hidden factors" (as in your original question) usually refers to. Google "Galactic Algorithm" or Flajolet-style Analysis of Algorithms. Donald Knuth and Kurt Mehlhorn do this sometimes. 2. Hardware caching doesn't know about the size of your nodes. It caches 64-bytes (or a page address, in the TLB) of nearby data. The top very few levels in a binary tree are in cache at once, so that doesn't save you much. 3. Yes, I am sure about that. Most modern vEB explanations explain how to use HTs to save space.

Comment: @jbapple My apologies - I missed the detail about hash tables in your previous post. I'm aware that you can count up the number of operations performed exactly (I've read Knuth, Mehlhorn, and Flajolet's work in the past), but it seems like that's tough for vEB trees with hash tables because each operation would require O(log log U) hash lookups, a large number of comparisons against the external min and max values, and a large number of bit operations. Ultimately, though, I think the best way to resolve this would be to just look up how they do in practice. :-) I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I just did a pretty bog-standard vEB tree in C++ and I'm getting 1 microsecond for the average time to insert a random 32-bit int (when inserting 20M of them). std::set take 1.5 microseconds for the same operation. I expect the vEB tree could get below 0.6 microseconds, since it uses std::unordered_set right now, and that is very slow.

Comment: Huh! I had read a number of sources saying that vEB trees weren't fast enough to be practical, but I guess they're either stale or incorrect. Thanks for running those numbers - I really appreciate it!